# About developing servers with sockets in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two classes in short here they are:

```
public final class ServerMain
{

      static List<Table> s_AvailableGameTables = new Vector<Table>(); 
      static List<Table> s_OccupiedGameTables = new Vector<Table>(); 
      static List<ServerThread> s_PlayersOnServer = new Vector<ServerThread>();
...
}
class ServerThread extends Thread{
...}
```

`ServerMain` is the server itself, and it manages the `ServerThreads` by allocating a new `ServerThread` for each user who has just connected to the `ServerMain`.

My questions are simple:

1. When I'm currently running in the specific ServerThread and I want to access some static lists on the serverMain and to update them how can I do that , if I've already "left" the area of the ServerMain while being in the specific thread which runs in the background.
   Is the only way is to hold a reference from each serverthread to papa ServerMain?
2. Maybe it can cause some problems as if at the same time two areas of the code can update the same list the ServerMain itself and the ServerThread which now knows who is the big boss around?
3. General question: does sockets programming means UDP or TCP?

I'd like to hear some good advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: General question: does sockets programming means UDP or TCP? - You have both `Socket` for TCP and `DatagramSocket` for UDP in Java

Comment: You should not accept the first answer that comes in a few minutes after you post your question. You should give it a few minutes to see all of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, you wouldn't need an instance to access *static* members of ServerMain, assuming they are accessible (e.g. they are `public`) you can access them as `ServerMain.MyVar`.

For #2, yes, you would need to look into using the `synchronized` statement to prevent multiple threads for writing to the list at the same time, or use a thread safe list implementation.

For #3, the term 'sockets programming' can refer to either UDP or TCP.  Which kind of socket you use will depend on what kind of app you are implementing.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean about Thread safe list implementation?

Comment: @Loduwijk - he already mentioned that they were static.  But they would need to be both static and public (or perhaps package level) to be accessible.

Comment: @GAEBegginer - Something like what you get from `Collections.synchronizedList()` would be a thread safe list implementation.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje Oh right. Thanks. You emphasized public and not static, so I misunderstood you. I originally gave a -1 but I'm cancelling the -1 now.

Comment: It won't let me cancel my downvote because it has been too long? It has been just over 10 minutes, how is that too long? That is idiotic. Sorry Eric.

Comment: Actually, it says "Unless the answer is edited." Care to edit your answer? It would even be legit (not an abuse of the "unless edited rule") if you edited it by making the word "static" in your first sentence bold.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you can reference it like 'normal'.  In the sense that there is no syntactic changes for actually referencing things from a different thread rather than a different object.  Now, you may need to synchronize access to it, but I don't really see that as changing *how* you reference things.
2. Synchronize the list (preferably use the java.util.concurrent package).  Make sure that the Tables themselves are thread-safe as well.
3. Neither, a socket uses a transport protocol, but it could be UDP, TCP, or whatever else.  To clarify, you can't determine what transport protocol is being used just by saying you're using a socket; you'd have to specify which protocol you're actually using.

Comment: 1) No you can't. (perhaps elaborate on what you mean by 'like normal'?) 2) No problems with your statement here, that is correct. 3) Both incorrect and correct at the same time since you contradicted yourself in that sentence. Elaborate?

Comment: 1) The semantics don't change for referencing something for a different thread.  If you're referencing a static member from a different class, or thread it's syntactically the same (you *might* need some more boilerplate to make it thread-safe but that's it). 3) It's not one or the other, it can use essentially any transport protocol.  I don't see how that is in any way contradictory.

Comment: 3) Ok, I see what you mean, though that's not what you said originally, as you said "neither" which is incorrect. And I read his "TCP or UDP" to mean "does socket programming refer to these?" rather than "Which does it refer to: (TCP but not UDP) or (UDP but not TCP)?" That is, a normal or as opposed to an xor. I still think that's what he meant, though seeing your take on it now I can see that he might mean it more like an xor as you took it.

Comment: 1) GAEBegginer did not specify that the issue was accessing the data from a different thread; it looks to me like he is merely asking about accessing the data from the other object, regardless of whether it's in another thread (though there does seem to be some confusion about that matter, perhaps GAEB is new and is trying to do concurrency before even having a grasp of basic Java? Not sure). What he said, though, is a different "area," which doesn't say either way. Still, his question #1 doesn't sound like a concurrency/threading issue though he mentions the thread; they use the same memory.

Comment: 3) Socket programming never means either of them, seeing a socket is not the same as a protocol, nor does i imply anything about the transport protocol being used.  It *can* use UDP or TCP, but it isn't required to, thus when you say I'm using sockets one can never definitively tell what transport protocol you're using without additional information, which is why I said neither.

Comment: I guess we both read the question and legitimately took it to mean two almost completely different things. In the light of your take on the question, I understand your points better now. Still, I don't like the the whole "like 'normal'" thing, as that can be very interpretive. Could you just change that to reflect what you said in your comment? You could even just copy/paste your comment, appending it after your "like normal" sentence.

Comment: Ok, that last comment makes more sense. Still, he asked what "socket **programming**" refers to. Regardless of whatever you want to define a socket as, whenever I hear people use the term "socket programming" it has always been in reference to network-related code in general, regardless of the technicalities. I would say that the term "socket programming" is therefore engineering slang and doesn't even need to be strictly defined, even if what precisely "a socket" is does happen to be well defined. I'm not really arguing anymore, I guess I'm just sort of explaining for the benefit of the post.

Comment: Saying you're writing network related code still doesn't tell you what transport protocol is being used ;-)  BTW this should probably be moved to chat, but I don't have enough reputation to move it there.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can access as normal if you use a synchronized list (i.e., `Vector`, one of the lists from the java.util.concurrent package, or if it's a better fit `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`).
2. Vector is already 'synchronized', but be aware that you have to synchronize transactions manually (i.e., `synchronized (vector) { vector.add(..); vector.remove(..); }`). The synchronisation it employs by default essentially stops list method calls from interrupting currently-executing user-defined transactions and currently-executing method calls on the list. I'd advise using `Collections.synchronizedList(list)` instead of `Vector`, although they both do the same job, really.
3. `ServerSocket` / `Socket` is TCP, `DatagramSocket` is UDP.

Comment: Odd, I was sure I wrote UDP. Oops :) Thanks very much for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

1) That is one of the possibilities. In general, when you need to access another object methods, the best way is to keep the reference (directly or indirectly). Yet, as it is supposed that you'll only have a ServerMain object, you could try to declare static methods or use the singleton construction (private constructor, you can only access a getInstance() static method that returns a shared object).

2) Synchronization of access between threads is a lengthy subject and many books have been written about it. The simplest way is to use a `synchronized` method (or block) and do all race sensitive commands inside. But be conscient that this probably these synchronized blocks will later become your main bottleneck. When you have more practice, study java synchronization methods.

3) As others java stated, you just open a socket that listens to a protocol in a given port number. You can decide if you want it to be UDP or TCP. Of course, keep in mind that with UDP maybe the message that you receive won't be complete, so it will have to be dealt with by your code.

Comment: +1 given, but I have one nitpick: To make something a singleton you don't have to do it any single specific way, such as "private constructor and and use getInstance()".

Comment: You are right, that was just an example in order to be more graphic.

Answer (score 0):

1) That would be *a* way and probably a preferred way, though not necessarily the *only* way.

Also, the reference does not need to be owned by the ServerThread. Since ServerMain is likely a singleton, I have found in situations like this that it makes sense to give that Singleton a static variable which references itself. Then, from any ServerThread, you could do

```
class ServerThread extends Thread
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        ServerMain.serverMain.whatever();
    }
}
```

2) Yes, that **will** cause problems. Read the [Java Concurrency Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), specifically the parts about synchronization. This is a topic too broad to cover easily in an answer here. But for a quick and dirty answer, check out synchronized methods. If you just make the method that handles this list access synchronized, then it will be safe. Of course, depending on your needs, locking the list access might take away any performance gain from your threads.

3) It doesn't necessarily have to, but it generally does. "TCP socket" is even more likely than "UDP socket", but both work. If you want a dedicated and reliable connection for an entire, prolonged transaction, you should probably use TCP. TCP makes guarantees that data was received and that it was received in a certain order.